# AWS RAM utilization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to monitor AWS RAM utilisation. I could able to monitor CPU utilisation. Reason is understand the RAM utilisation for the current load, so I can plan the RAM for the targeted load while going live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push custom metrics to cloudwatch and create alerts as well. The standard way to do is is to use the famous Mon scripts.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html

It is basically a perl script which you can set on the crontab to run every 5 minutes, and it can grab server metrics like memory, disk, and swap.

to monitor memory you can set this line on crontab

```
*/5 * * * * ./mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-used-incl-cache-buff --mem-util --mem-used --mem-avail
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me out, will check this out and accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

ssh into the box and use top: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/top-command-in-linux-with-examples/

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me out, will check this out and accept the answer.